# Expressing $\frac {x^n}{(1-x)^n}$ as a generating function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

How did they get the following:

$$\frac {x^n}{(1-x)^n} = \sum\limits_{m}{m-1 \choose n-1}{x^m}$$

Comment: Please reread what you wrote and fix it. The $n$ on the left can't be the same as the $n$ in $x^n$ on the right. Otherwise the right side is a series where everything has the same term $x^n$.

Comment: Who are "they"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1-x)^n}=(1-x)^{-n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^k$,

$\displaystyle \frac{x^n}{(1-x)^n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^{n+k}=\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}\binom{m-1}{m-n}x^m=\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}\binom{m-1}{n-1}x^m$ $\;\;$(letting $m=n+k$)

Comment: Sorry, is the first step just a property of $\frac {1} {(1-x)^n}$

Comment: @wallace: Yes. You can prove it by induction on $n$, among other ways.

Comment: One way to get this is to use the generalized Binomial theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem